# fields not allowed in C# interface

Tags: c#, java

There are quite a lot of deviations in Java and C# languages, one of which I observed was we cannot add variable constants in an interface. Being from Java background I got baffled to see compilation error when I tried this.

Does anyone has explanation why it is so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A field is an *implementation detail* of a class and should not be exposed an its interface.
An interface is a way to abstract away implementation details of a class. These two concepts look contradictory and don't really fit together.

You *can* declare properties in interfaces instead.

---

***UPDATE (after realizing the question was about constants, not variable fields):*** I *think* (purely my personal speculation) that Java decided to allow such a  construct because it didn't have `enum` types back then. C# has had enums since the beginning and preferred those to constants most of the time. Moreover, you can create a static class in C# and add everything you like in it and ship it along the interface without any real hassles. Supporting such a construct would just make interface definitions more complicated.

Comment: You can't declare "normal" fields in Java interfaces either - but you can declare constants. That's what the OP is talking about.

Comment: And i am know what an interface is no need of explanation onthat.
I have mentioned that its constant i am trying to add,

Comment: @Jon: I see. I thought the question is more general. That would be weird, anyway but I don't have a theoretical reason for not doing this (or maybe since I've a C# background, it looks odd to me).

Comment: @afshari you are comparing apples and oranges .Having interface constants instead of enums is very lame explanation.

Comment: @Ravisha: I'm not directly comparing those. What I'm saying is that not having this feature simplifies the language. Especially since *some* of their added-value is already provided by enums, the feature is already less exciting in C#.

Comment: Dear afshari you are biased by the idea of C# implementation.There is scope for using constants in interface which is why it is there in java.what is the main reason behind restriction being there in C# is my question

Comment: @Ravisha: I've never claimed my opinion is unbiased but that doesn't matter. This feature does not exist in C# because the designers didn't think it's useful enough in comparison to costs.  I simply explained *my own speculation* about why *they* didn't think they should include it (correctly, IMHO) in this answer: you can already accomplish what you could do with interface fields with little more code in the worst case.

Comment: @afshari  Having this argument wont carry anywhere.Anyway thanks for offering help

Answer (score 3):

I've rarely wanted to have an actual constant in an interface - they usually make more sense in classes. The practice of using a Java interface to *just* contain constants (in order to reduce typing in classes that use them) is nasty; I'd only put constants in interfaces where they were related to functionality within the interface itself.

However, on occasion I've thought it would be nice to be able to define an enum within an interface, if that's the only context in which the enum is anticipated to be used. Interestingly, VB allows this even though C# doesn't.

Effectively both of these would be a way of turning the interface into a "mini-namespace" in its own right. However, I can't say I've missed it very often when writing C#. As the C# team is fond of saying, features aren't *removed* - they're *added*, and the cost of adding a feature is very high. That means the feature really needs to pull its weight - there has to be a significant benefit before the feature is added. I personally wouldn't put this very high up on the list.

---

Related thought: it might be nice to be able to define a nested *class* within the interface, usually an implementation of the interface - either to express its contracts or to act as a "default" implementation for situations where there is such a thing.

Comment: Does the CLR support nested types in interfaces under the hood? Never tried that.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think it must do for enums, so that the VB code will work. I very much doubt that it's restricted to just enums.

Comment: Just tested it. It perfectly supports nested types (even classes) in interfaces. Now that I think about it, there's no reason CLR shouldn't have supported it. Interfaces are not very different from classes at the IL level.

Comment: You don't need constants in interfaces. Features costs a lot. Sure, but the designers didn't omit it because you didn't need them. It's an argumentation for the decision, but not an explanation. I don't downvote, but I won't upvote either.

Comment: @Peteter: I don't understand your reasoning. Something not being particularly useful *is* an explanation of the decision not to include this feature in C#, and I also explained why it's not a particularly useful feature. What sort of explanation were you expecting which isn't provided here?

Comment: @JonSkeet First of; Your answer answers the question, but half of it also answers (I should presume) a lot of other questions regarding 'why is feature X is in or out of c#?'. Second, the half that is specific to this question, I find is rather subjective.  (Don't get me all wrong, I do like to take in other peoples experience on SO, and maybe I'm bitter because no one said something like 'The design spec says A' or 'That would break the optimization of B')

Comment: @Peterer: So you're complaining because my answer does *more* than just answer this specific question? As for being subjective - yes, no-one who isn't on the C# design team or have access to their notes can really give anything more than speculation. It feels like an odd criticism...

Answer (score 0):

and adding constants to interfaces is discouraged in Java too (according to Effective Java at least)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having constants in interfaces.  There is something wrong with implementing interfaces to get some easy-to-type constants.  This has been handled with Static imports instead.

Comment: I didn no about static imports thanks for mentioning it anderson

Comment: Static imports are an abomination and just lead to confusion, as one cant really tell where the constant etc comes from without help from the IDE. Its a shame java was changed to pander to the whims of lazy people, its not that hard to qualify each member access.

Answer (score -1):

Adding constants to an interface is wrong and should almost never be done. In the past many people declared Interfaces with many constants and then made another class implement this interface so they could make use of the constants without qualifying said constant. This is of course another anti pattern and was only done because people were lazy. If you really want a constant in an interface define a method that returns that constant.

Comment: define a method that returns constant in interface!!
I didn no we can implement method in interface.some new concept?