# How to associate constants with an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, idl, webidl

Some languages let you associate a constant with an interface:

- [A Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9700081/49942)
- [A PhP example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5350672/49942)

The W3C abstract interfaces do the same, for example:

```
// Introduced in DOM Level 2:
interface CSSValue {

  // UnitTypes
  const unsigned short      CSS_INHERIT                    = 0;
  const unsigned short      CSS_PRIMITIVE_VALUE            = 1;
  const unsigned short      CSS_VALUE_LIST                 = 2;
  const unsigned short      CSS_CUSTOM                     = 3;

  attribute DOMString       cssText;
  attribute unsigned short  cssValueType;
};
```

I want to define this interface such that it can be called from C#.

Apparently C# cannot define a constant associated with an interface.

- What is the usual way to translate such an interface to C#?
- Are there any 'canonical' C# bindings for the DOM interfaces?
- Although C# cannot, is there another .NET language which can define constants associated with an interface?

Comment: I would think enumerations are what you are looking for.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175734/fields-not-allowed-in-c-sharp-interface for more info.

Comment: @Oded An enum must have a name, which cannot be the same as the name of the interface, and which cannot be defined inside the interface. Client code which (only) knows the IDL interface would not know the name of the artificial C# enum. Instead, there should be constant integer values associated with the interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# 8 now allows constants in an `interface` definition.

Comment: How? I'm using C# 8 and the `public const type name = value` syntax is failing compilation with "target runtime doesn't support default interface implementation".

Comment: @glen-little can you include a link to the C# documentation that support your claim. I can't find any

Comment: [interface doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface#c-language-specification)

Comment: It is important to point out that constants on an interface cannot be inherited, implemented or overridden by an implementing class.  Furthermore, they can only be statically accessed via the interface's type and not via an instance or via an implementing class's type.

Comment: `public const int test = 1;` works in C# 8

Answer (score 26):

I added a Get only property and backed it up with a const in the definition.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string ConstValue { get; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string ConstValue => _constValue;
    private string _constValue = "My constant";
}
```

Answer (score 22):

To answer your third question:

> Although C# cannot, is there another .NET language which can define constants associated with an interface?

C++/CLI allows you to define `literal` values in an interface, which are equivalent to `static const` values in C#.

```
public interface class ICSSValue
{
public:
    literal short CSS_INHERIT = 0;
    literal short CSS_PRIMITIVE_VALUE = 1;
    literal short CSS_VALUE_LIST = 2;
    literal short CSS_CSS_CUSTOM = 3;

    property DOMString^ cssText;
    property ushort cssValueType;
}
```

You could then access the values via C#:

```
public static void Main()
{
    short primitiveValue = ICSSValue.CSS_PRIMITIVE_VALUE;

    Debug.Assert(primitiveValue == 1);
}
```

See [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yzft952%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details.

Disclaimer:
The design decision to disallow constant values in interfaces was a good one. An interface which exposes implementation details is most likely a leaky abstraction. In this example CSS Value Type is probably better off being an enumeration.

Comment: While I appreciate that the CLR lets you do this, it seems counter-intuitive to write your interfaces in C++ just to be able to have constants in them. But OK.

Comment: @kprobst I do not disagree with you :)

Answer (score 17):

If you want a place to store your constants I would use a static class:

```
public static class MyConstants
{
    public const int first = 1;
    public const int second = 2;
    public const string projectName = "Hello World";
}
```

That is (at least one) common standard.

Comment: Clients would need to know the name of the artificial static class (as they would, alternatively, need to know the name of an artificial enum type). Is there are any "common standard" for the name of that static class?

Comment: @ChrisW Just like they would need to know the name of the artificial interface...It's not any different.

Answer (score 7):

C# doesn't allow constants in interfaces because a constant is an implementation facet which theoretically does not belong in a type that only defines a behavior protocol.

I suspect the Java folks allow const fields in interfaces either because an interface is treated internally as some kind of abstract class, or because they needed that to make up for some deficiency in the type system, like enums.

I'm not sure what you mean by "canonical bindings for the DOM interfaces". C# does not run in a browser.

That said, you'll need to put your constants somewhere else, like a struct, or an enum (if they are numeric). Perhaps following some kind of naming convention would help -- if your interface is `IFooBar` then maybe the struct that contains your constant could be called `IFooSetttings` or `IFooValues` or whatever is appropriate.

I don't know any CLR languages other than C# and VB.NET, but I'm pretty sure VB doesn't allow this (although it's been a while).

Comment: +1 The CLR does allow for constant values in interfaces but AFAIK none of the mainstream languages support this by design.

Comment: Java `enum`s are more powerful than C# `enum`s. In fact, they're the only thing I prefer in Java. The answer is because they are treated as a purely `abstract class` under the hood. The DOM interfaces are released as IDL(s) by the W3C so that new browsers can roll their own implementations while still fitting the standard.

Comment: Good answer, particularly the part about enums.  Constants in interfaces in Java are almost universally used because of the lack of enums (until 1.5).

Comment: @MattDavey Are you saying they can be defined by emitting IL? Would they be defined as static fields? If that's done then can a mainstream languages, like C#, then reference such a field?

Comment: `I'm not sure what you mean by "canonical bindings for the DOM interfaces"` -- I expect there must be (one or more) interfaces to let C# access the browser DOM interfaces.

Comment: @ChrisW theoretically yes. Upon investigation I have found that you can define literal values in interfaces in C++/CLI.. `public interface class IExample { public: literal float Pi = 3.14159f }` which is equivalent to a `static const` variable.

Comment: @ChrisW not _in_ a browser, only if you create a forms application, host a WebBrowser control and then interact with it. I'm not sure if this is what you mean - there's also C# to JavaScript compilers suck as SharpKit.

Comment: Since when is a constant an implementation facet? I don't agree with the C# designers on this one. It forces us into the workarounds you mention.

Answer (score 4):

I use SO all the time but this is my first ever post here. I found this post, trying to solve the same problem. When I saw the post on using a static class (by Servy) it got me thinking about solving this by embedding the Interface inside that static class.

```
// define an interface with static content
public static class X {
    // define the interface to implement
    public interface Interface {
        string GetX();
    }

    // static content available to all implementers of this interface
    public static string StandardFormat(object x) {
        return string.Format("Object = {0}", x.ToString());
    }
}

// Implement the interface
public class MyX : X.Interface {
    public override string ToString() {
        return "MyX";
    }

    #region X.Interface Members

    public string GetX() {
        // use common code defined in the "interface"
        return X.StandardFormat(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class will do everything an interface will do (well, apart from pass a `typeof(T).IsInterface` test) and allow constants.

The objection to constants (or enums) embedded in interfaces is misplaced. It's a naming issue. Naming constants in the very precise context where they have meaning is better than naming them out of context.

Comment: how about multiple inheritance?

Comment: I agree with you: constants should be in the context of which they are intended to be used. A constant value is not logic or behavior and therefore not implementation. It's just a value. This conversation is testament to an artificial constraint of a language.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem - need to define constants in interface.
Found yet another possibility: by using extension methods on interface.
Like this:

```cs
public interface IFoo
{
    // declarations
}
 
public static class IFooExtensions
{
    public static int Bar(this IFoo x) => 50;
}
```

This, however, will require instance of interface to get constant from it:

```cs
IFoo foo;
foo.Bar();
```

And you can also use this constant in interface implementations:

```cs
public class Foo: IFoo
{
    public Foo() {
        var x = this.Bar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try define it thought method parameters and/or returned values

```
public enum IFIleValue
{
    F_OK = 0,
    F_WRONG_NAME = -1,
    F_ERROR_OBJECT_DATA = -2,
};

public interface IFile
{
     IFIleValue New(String Name=null);
     IFIleValue Open(String Path);
     IFIleValue Save();
     IFIleValue SaveAs(String Path);
     IFIleValue Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A custom attribute can be used:

```
[Constant("CSS_INHERIT", 0)]
[Constant("CSS_PRIMITIVE_VALUE", 1)]
public interface BlaBla
```

The custom attribute class could look like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class ConstantAttribute: Attribute
{
    public ConstantAttribute(string key, object value)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Constants can be retrieved using

```
object[] attributes = typeof(BlaBla).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConstantAttribute),
    inherit: false);
```