# Generic Identifier handling implementations

Tags: c#, generics

Since my application has to work with a lot of identifiers, I thought about abstracting them using a `Id<T>` class. This class would work like a Guid, it has a `CreateNew()` method and so on, but would create a different Id depending on the type of T.

Examples:

`var id = Id<Individual>.CreateNew(); // == "INDIVIDUAL-12345"`
`var id = Id<Organization>.CreateNew(); // == "ORGANIZATION-67890"`

Now, `Individual` and `Organization` implement the interface `IUser`.

Now I would like my Id<> to handle different implementations, but this does not work.

i.e. consider the following class, using Ids:

```
class Transaction{
    private Id<IUser> _sender;
    private Id<IUser> _receiver;
    private Amount _amount;

    public Transaction(Id<IUser> sender, Id<IUser> receiver, Amount amount {...}
}
```

I would like to be able to call:

```
new Transaction(Id<Individual>.CreateNew(), Id<Organization>.CreateNew(), new Amount());
```

but this is not possible as the constructor requires the types to be `Id<IUser>`. Can you think about any workaround?

---

**Update**

Thanks for the answers until now.
`Id<IUser>` is just an example (and the content of IUser is not that important here), I'd like to support identifiers for many objects (10/15, more in the future?).

`Id<T>` uses a static class as helper, called TypesMatcher, whose job is to translate a type to a prefix (i.e. "Individual", "Organization", "Transaction"..).

`Id<T>.CreateNew()` looks more or less like this:

```
    [Pure]
    public static Id<T> CreateNew()
    {
        if (!TypesMatcher.IsSupported<T>()) throw new Exception($"Type {typeof(T)} is not supported.");

        string prefix = TypesMatcher.GetPrefixForType<T>();
        string body = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        return new Id<T>($"{prefix}-{body}");
    }
```

Comment: Please, share `Id<T>` declaration

Comment: share, also, the `IUser` interface definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by looking into your desired syntax: `Id<Individual>.CreateNew()`.

It means there should be an `Id<T>` class and have a static `CreateNew` method.

The `static` method cannot be overridable, so a good way to make it extensible, is injecting the behavior inside the method.

So for each entity type we can create a class like `SomeEntityId` deriving from `Id<SomeEntity>`. The class should contain the custom logic for generating the id. Then we can register them in a DI container. Then in the static `CreateNew` method, I'd get instance of the registered classes based on `T` from the container. This way you can inject the custom logic based on `T`.

I'll also change the `Transaction` class to rely on `IId<IUser>`, this way I can create a [Variant Generic Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) like `IId<T>`.

**Example**

```
public interface IId<out T> where T : IUser
{
    string Value { get; }
}
public class Id<T> : IId<T> where T : IUser
{
    public string Value { get; protected set; }
    protected virtual Id<T> GenerateId() => new Id<T>() { Value = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}" };
    public static Id<T> CreateNew() => Container.GetInstance<Id<T>>().GenerateId();
}
public class IndividualId : Id<Individual>
{
    protected override Id<Individual> GenerateId()
    {
        var instance = new IndividualId();
        instance.Value = $"IndividualId-{Guid.NewGuid()}"; //Example of custom logic
        return instance;
    }
}
public class Transaction
{
    private IId<IUser> _sender;
    private IId<IUser> _receiver;
    public Transaction(IId<IUser> sender, IId<IUser> receiver) { }
}
```

For each type which you have custom logic, make sure you register the type instance for `Id<yourtype>`, for example register `IndividualId` for `Id<Individual>` in the container.

Then for usage, you can use this:

```
new Transaction(Id<Individual>.CreateNew(), Id<Organization>.CreateNew());
```

Comment: I tried to share the way that I think about this problem. You know about the detailed requirement better, but if you know how to approach the problem, it will not hard for you to handle the details.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. The only issue is that also other classes (not implementing IUser) will need an Id. So, for example, how could I marry your code with a `Id<Transaction>.CreateNew()`?

Comment: In this case, the `where` should be `where T : IEntity` . And any entity should derive from `IEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am getting your goal/the problem you are trying to solve here.

Generics are about allowing a person that is using your code to put in any class, *without breaking compile time type checks*. Prior to generics, we had to either make a special collection for every type or use Object as the type. One was a unsuiteable amount of work with tons of pitfalls. The other just broke type safety. It is just a mess we mostly prefer to stay burried in pre-generics history. Still I feel it is important to understand why Generics exist, what they are about solving and what they can not solve.

As you use a Interface function to access the values, they can only be resolved at runtime. While they might be a compile time constant in the class, there is no way for the compiler to ever be **sure** of it as they are handed out by a function at runtime. However it seems possible to add a sort-of-compile time Constant to Interfaces, with the [Literal Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12752750/3346583). But I am unsure if Implementers of that interface can add a tiffrent "typeID" value. I just read about this being a thing, while writing.

Personally that code you shared reminds me a lot of a variant of the Factory/not quite singleton pattern. A factory method where the same input (the same Collection, Type) will result in the same output. But I can not find a example right now.

With the shared code, the only thing I can see being made generic is the transaction Method:

```
public <senderType, ReceiverType> Transaction (senderType sender, ReceiverType receiver, Amount amount) { }
```

But again, I am unsure what you tried to do and particular the problem you tried to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Generics cannot handle any idea of inheritance.
Covariance is only available on Interfaces.

If you have a covariant interface

```
  interface IID<out IUser>
  {
        IID<IUser> CreateNew();
  }
```

And you use this instead of `ID<User>`, and Individual and Organization implement `IUser`,
and `ID<Invdidual>` implements `IID<Individual>` and `ID<Organization>` implements `IID<Organization>`.

Then you can make this assigment:

```
  IID<IUser> id = = ID<Individual>.CreateNew();
```

or use it as a Parameter.

But on the other hand side, to use it in this way:

```
  IID<Individual> id =  (IID<Individual>)ID<Individual>.CreateNew();
```

you would need a cast.